# 403 Request Failure Despite working Service Account google.oauth2

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am consistently running into problems querying in python using the following libraries. I am given a 403 error, that the "user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permissions for the project I am accessing.

```
#BQ libs
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('path.json')



#BigQuery Connection and query execution
bqProjectId = 'poject_id'
project_id = bqProjectId
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

query = client.query("SELECT * FROM `table`")
Output = Query.to_dataframe()
```

I am using the same service account json file, and same query in Java, R, and even on a BI tool. All three successfully retreived the data. So this seems to be python specific.

I have tried starting with a clean environment. I even reinstalled anaconda. Nothing seems to work. What are some possible culprits here?

*Obviously my path, query, and creds are different for that actual script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code by including access scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` for your requirement.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

project_id = "project-id"
client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project=credentials.project_id,
)
sql_query ="SELECT * FROM table"
query_job = client.query(sql_query)
results = query_job.result()
df = results.to_dataframe()
print (df)
```

As per the error message you are getting, service account is missing the `BigQuery Admin` Role which includes the permission `bigquery.readsessions.create`.

For more information regarding BigQuery IAM roles you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).